# Write current url in an iframe by javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am trying to write current website url in a frame using javascript. Butt my methods does not working... What I want to do is to write the current url path into this code instead of "CURRENT+WEBSITE+URL+HERE" text.

My current iframe code:

```
<iframe allowtransparency='true' frameborder='0' height='600px' id='web search' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' scrolling='no' src='http://mysite.com/display?sid=1770469&title_color=0000FF&text_color=000000&background_color=FFFFFF&border_color=FFFFFF&url_color=000000&url=CURRENT+WEBSITE+URL+HERE&b=4' title='Find It' width='160px'></iframe>
```

In the iframe url src you will get "**CURRENT+WEBSITE+URL+HERE**" text where I want to put the current URL, so assuming a path of that site is "**http://mysite.com/go/went/gone.html**" , the iframe will show this url: `http://mysite.com/display?sid=1770469&title_color=0000FF&text_color=000000&background_color=FFFFFF&border_color=FFFFFF&url_color=000000&url=http://mysite.com/go/went/gone.html&b=4' title='Find It' width='160px`

It would me much better for me if you would code it...

Comment: *it would me much better for me if you code it to me .... thanks* You don't really want to say this, it implies you have no intentions of learning anything which is what this site is for. You want to learn right?

Comment: Show us the code that generates the iframe!

Comment: ow yaa... :) "Happy to be learn that" @Esailija

Comment: @Bergi that iframe is static, so it can be use in HTML pages...

Comment: Well it cannot be static if you want to dynamically add current website url there.

Comment: @rakibtg: Then just take the url of that static page from your browser and insert it in the static code.

Comment: @Bergi ,@Esailija ya, i know that ... i wanna use this code in a block of my blog so this iframe will automatically get those blog pages path.. any idea?

Comment: You don't know the URL of your own blog? Does this blog use any kind of CMS?

Comment: oh, actually this on blogger.com thats why javascript is needed

Comment: u guys just have some useless comments

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current URL with Javascript using document.URL

```
var currentURL = document.URL;
```

You can then access or modify the iframe's source by accessing it's src property.

Example

```
var myFrame = document.getElementById('web search');
myFrame.src = 'some code ' + currentURL + 'some other code';
```

In theory, this will change the iframe's source to

```
some code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687605/write-current-url-in-an-iframe-by-javascript some other code
```

Here's a simple JSFiddle to get you going: http://jsfiddle.net/BBog/xSCpH/
Keep in mind that you need to get the iframe after the page loads, inside `window.onload`, something like

```
window.onload = function() {
    //some code
    ....
    var myFrame = document.getElementById('web search');
}
```

This is not something very difficult and you need to try do it yourself. StackOverflow's purpose is to help you learn, not to have someone else solve your problem.

On the long run, it would be so much better for you to code.
Give it a try and people (including myself) will be more willing to help you with that if you have a hard time understanding things.

Comment: well BBog. no need to patronize. greatest strength of SO is those simple copy paste examples that save a lot of time and quick learning. As a matter of fact answers without the sample codes should be pulled out of SO because they take long to comprehend.

Answer (score 0):

We can use encodeURIComponent(location.href).

**location.href** gives current location

**encodeURIComponent()**: will encode a URL parameter.

Example

```
    $('<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="width: 300px; height: 80px;'+
        '" src="http://www.facebook.com/widgets/like.php?href='+
            encodeURIComponent(location.href)+
        '"></iframe>').appendTo('#like-button')
```

For better Understanding please check

[Add Current page url to Iframe](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/facebook-iframe-like-button-add-current-page-url-to-href#fullResponseContainer_14737000003022759)

[encodeURIComponent 101](https://coderwall.com/p/y347ug/encodeuri-vs-encodeuricomponent)

Hope it helps someone